# SIGABRT when using NSDictionary setObject: forKey:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, plist, nsdictionary

I'm using a property-file with this structure:

```
maxRating     Number    --> 5
gradePercent  Dictonary
>grade1       Number    --> 0.85
>grade2       Number    --> 0.70
>grade3       Number    --> 0.55
>grade4       Number    --> 0.40
```

To read the properties I'm using

```
NSDictionary *plist = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filepath];

rating = [[plist objectForKey:@"maxRating"] intValue];
gradePercent = (NSMutableDictionary*)[[plist objectForKey:@"gradePercent"] copy];
```

Till here every thing works perfectly...I can get the right objects with `[gradePercent objectForKey:@"grade1"]`

but when I try to set one of them with

```
[gradePercent setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.90] forKey:@"grade1"]
```

I always get a SIGABRT error and the APP is crashing.

Does anyone see why this isn't working? Because I don't -.-

Comment: Enable NSZombie Environment variable and run the code again, check the logs

Comment: Are you declaring gradePercent as an NSMutableDictionary?

Comment: or replace the `copy` with `mutableCopy`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `NSDictionary` is immutable, and simply casting the pointer to `NSMutableDictionary *` doesn't make the object magically become mutable. So you need a mutable dictionary. You could do it like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *plist = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filepath];
```

Comment: The child dictionary `gradePercent` will still be immutable with this

Comment: @Jilouc: Right, for that `mutableCopy` must be used instead of `copy`.

Answer (score 4):

`[[plist objectForKey:@"gradePercent"] copy]` returns an immutable dictionary.

What you need is `[[plist objectForKey:@"gradePercent"] mutableCopy]`

Answer (score 1):

Because the dictionary you have is read only to get a Mutable dictionary from any dictionary you need to call addEntriesFromDictionary on a Muntable dictionary

e.g.

```
NSMutableDictionary* dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dict addEntriesFromDictionary:[plist objectForKey:@"gradePercent"]];
```

the [plist objectForKey:@"gradePercent"] is a NSDictionary and so cannot be added to. You cannot simply cast from NSDictionary* to NSMutableDictionary *.

Answer (score 1):

NSDictionary does not have a setObject: forKey: method